# Output image of RawTherapee is different

Tags: noise, rawtherapee

I modified a raw image using rawtherapee which looks like below screenshot in editor.

[image]

But when I export it (I have tried all options: jpeg,png, best quality etc), the output image is not same. It is comparatively bright and has noise. Even it losses the detailing.

[image]

How can I export the same image I see in the editor?

Comment: Whenever I face a problem, I think about stackexchange first. But thanks for your suggestion, I have posted on their forum as well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to know the reason. I used Tone Mapping with high strength. In this case the image is more noisy than the actual shown in the editor.